# Connect Tableau to .SQL File on Desktop or SharePoint

Tags: tableau-api, alteryx

Is it possible to have Tableau run a query that is stored in an external location such as SharePoint? If not, is Alteryx a tool with this particular capability?

I have a central location for my queries (SharePoint), which allows multiple people to edit the .SQL files saved there. These queries change regularly, but they end up being put into Excel files for reporting purposes. I want to be able to move from Excel to Tableau or Alteryx + Tableau. Ideally I would not have to store / edit queries within Tableau / Alteryx.

Comment: Yes, Alteryx would support this.  It has a "dynamic input" tool that could run the dynamic SQL, and also has hooks to either Sharepoint or a generic URL, which you would use to retrieve the text in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Alteryx would support this. It has a "dynamic input" tool that could run the dynamic SQL, and also has hooks to either Sharepoint or a generic URL, which you would use to retrieve the text in the first place.